# Change image with a press on the button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change my image to a gif with the use of a button, this part of the code i have working.
But now they asked me to change the gif back to the previous image with a second button (let's call it a stop button).

Here is the code i have to this point:

```
<script>
function pictureChange()
{
document.getElementById("theImage").src="http://www.animaties.com/data/media/194/vis-bewegende-animatie-0135.gif";
}
</script>
<body>
<img id="theImage" src="http://www.pastasite.nl/file/2011/11/vis.jpg">
<p><input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange()"></p>
</body>
```

The images are only for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `else` condition

```js
function pictureChange() {
  if (document.getElementById("theImage").src == "http://www.pastasite.nl/file/2011/11/vis.jpg") {
    document.getElementById("theImage").src = "http://www.animaties.com/data/media/194/vis-bewegende-animatie-0135.gif";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("theImage").src = "http://www.pastasite.nl/file/2011/11/vis.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="theImage" src="http://www.pastasite.nl/file/2011/11/vis.jpg">
<p>
  <input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange()">
</p>
```

Comment: @Bryan, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

Save original src in a data attribute before changing src

```js
function pictureChange() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("theImage");
  if (!elem.getAttribute("data-origsrc")) {
    elem.setAttribute("data-origsrc", elem.getAttribute('src'));
  }
  elem.src = "http://www.animaties.com/data/media/194/vis-bewegende-animatie-0135.gif";
}

function revert() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("theImage");
  elem.src = elem.getAttribute("data-origsrc");
}
```

```html
<img id="theImage" src="http://www.pastasite.nl/file/2011/11/vis.jpg">
<p>
  <input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange()">
  <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="revert()">
</p>
```